# Count unique subsequences

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I came across this question in a coding competition (Java-restricted) and I got a time-length-exceeded. I am unable to provide a link as the contest is closed now. Can I know how can I optimise this?

> **Unique Subsequences:**  You are given a randomly generated string of characters ranging from a to z. You are required to determine the
> number of unique subsequences that can be formed equal to this string
> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.
>
> Input Format :
>
> - The first line will contain t denoting the number of test cases
> - The first line of each test case contains n denoting the size of the string
> - The second line of each test case contains string s of size n
>
> We are supposed to print the count of unique subsequences that are
> possible in a-z format
>
> Constraints:
>
> $$1 \le t \le 10$$
>
> $$1 \le n \le 100000$$
>
> $$1 \le |S| \le 100000$$
>
> For Example :
>
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzz = 2
>
> abz = 0 (Doesn't have all the characters from a-z)
>
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyyzz = 4

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class TestClass {
    public static boolean check_String(String str) {
      boolean flag = str.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "")
                .replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "")
                .length() == 26;
        if(flag) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        
        int testcases = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        for(int itr = 0; itr < testcases; itr++) {
            long ans = 1;
            int str_len = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
            StringBuilder strbd = new StringBuilder();
            strbd.append(buffer.readLine());
            strbd.toString();
            if(str_len >= 26) {
                if(check_String(strbd.toString())) {
                    HashMap<Character,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
                    for(int itr2 = 0; itr2 < str_len; itr2++) {
                  
                        if(hashmap.containsKey(strbd.charAt(itr2))) {
                            hashmap.put(strbd.charAt(itr2),hashmap.get(strbd.charAt(itr2))+1);
                        } else {
                            hashmap.put(strbd.charAt(itr2),1);
                        }
                    }
                    for(int itr3 : hashmap.values()) {
                        ans = (ans * itr3)%1000000007;
                    }
                }   
            } else {
                ans = 0;
            }     
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: I consider this on-topic: we commonly cover programming challenge time-length-exceeded issues.

Comment: [Crossposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770501/optimised-approach-for-subsequences-in-java). That said, the approach doesn't look correct at all.

Comment: If the approach doesn't look correct at all, Can I know the correct approach?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245124/65105, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62770501/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).